# When using windbg is there a way to break on a specific CLR exception

Tags: c#, exception, clr, windbg

I'm debugging a production service which is at rare instances is throwing AppDomainUnloadedException. The exception contains no stacktrace or any kind of useful information about why it happens. So want to attach windbg and only break when AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown and not any other clr exception.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in windbg, but have recently done it with mdbg. See my blogpost: http://nickvane.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-net-applications-in.html . Instead of using 'ca ex' you could use 'ca AppDomainUnloadedException'

Comment: Thanks, that worked for all other exception, except the one I was trying to catch. :(
It does how ever gets caught by the UnhandledException handler but without a stacktrace or any other useful information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're look for the `!soe` command (Stop On Exception) syntax should be something like:

```
!soe System.AppDomainUnloadedException 1
```

Comment: How can I revert the `!soe` command? I want to break again in all the exceptions.